# Disable web search from Google Chrome address bar

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome address bar (or omnibox as they call it) is quite annoying for me. I don't want to use it for web search. If I type `kitten` in the address bar I want my browser to connect to the `kitten` host or give me an error if it does not exist. Completion suggestions (aka. recommendations) according to browser history are fine.

Expectation:

- The `kitten` host exists => Go to `http://kitten/` or `https://kitten/` or give error that both :80 and :443 are ignoring or rejecting connection.
- The `kitten` host does not exist => Error page: Host not found

Reality:

- The `kitten` host exists => Search results for `kitten` appear.
- The `kitten` host does not exist => Search results for `kitten` appear.

I have a `/etc/hosts` (or Windows equivalent) file with one word entries in it. I want to use them from my Chrome browser, because I am forced to use Chrome for whatever reason. The same setting in Firefox for is to set `keyword.enable=false` in `about:config`.

So the question is: can I disable web search from Google Chrome address bar?

Comment: Bingleducking gave me several pages that purport to instruct you in disabling this.

Comment: alternatively you can make them actual domains, such as kitten.com, then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy workaround is to add a `/` to the end of the hostname. That way Google Chrome will not try to use it as a search term, it will treat it like a host name exclusively.

Result of `mistypedhostname/` (Hungarian)

[image: Result of mistypedhostname/ (Hungarian)]

Answer (score -1):

Additional information:
Address bar as web search is an incredible information leak!
You mistype something (maybe even with passwords in it) and all the address bar contents will be leaked to the outside world!
Terrible!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1120774)

Comment: @Chris56 It's not an answer. Please make it into a comment.